# Fluent NHibernate odd mapping issue in parent/child relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Foo class that can have a Parent Foo, many Child Foo's, and many Snafu's. NHibernate is generating a Foo_id and a ParentFoo_id in both the Foo and Snafu tables. Not only is the duplicate field a waste of memory, but it also causes problems when one of the duplicate references ends up NULL. This is using SQL Server 2012.

Why is this occuring and how can I get this to generate a single Foo_id?

Foo class and mapping:

```
public class Foo {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Foo ParentFoo { get; set; }
  public IList<Foo> ChildFoos { get; set; }
  public IList<Snafu> Snafus { get; set; }
}
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {
  public FooMap() {
    Id(x=>x.Id);
    References(x=>x.ParentFoo);
    HasMany(x=>x.ChildFoos);
    HasMany(x=>x.Snafus);
  }
}

----Resulting Foo Table----
Id (PK, int, not null)
Foo_id (FK, int, null)        <- refers to ParentFoo
ParentFoo_id (FK, int, null)  <- also refers to ParentFoo
```

Snafu class and mapping:

```
public class Snafu {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Foo Foo { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class SnafuMap : ClassMap<Snafu> {
  public SnafuMap() {
    Id(x=>x.Id);
    References(x=>x.Foo);
    Map(x=>x.Value);
  }
}

----Resulting Snafu Table----
Id (PK, int, not null)
Foo_id (FK, int, null)        <- refers to Foo
ParentFoo_id (FK, int, null)  <- refers to same Foo
Value (nvarchar(255), null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent foo should be inverse, and you need to specify column for both mappings. 
So correct mapping should look like following

```
References(x => x.ParentFoo)
    .Column("PARENT_FOO_ID");

HasMany(x => x.ChildFoos)
    .Inverse() // Important!
    .KeyColumn("PARENT_FOO_ID");
```

Comment: I had to do similar for Snafus `HasMany(x => x.Snafus).Inverse().KeyColumn("FOO_ID");`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to specify the column name explicitly in the References mapping? I'm guessing but this is how I've done some of my mappings for similar situations.

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo> {
  public FooMap() {
    Id(x=>x.Id);
    References(x=>x.ParentFoo, "ParentFoo_id");
    HasMany(x=>x.ChildFoos);
    HasMany(x=>x.Snafus);
  }
}
```